# Google App Script to get email from gmail into a third party application

Tags: php, mysql, google-apps-script

I need to write a google app script that reads an unread email and sends the body and sender details to my php application which is external. The functionality that i want is the script should run every 5 minutes and update in my MySQL database the details of the mail i.e. sender, body , date if there is an unread mail. I am not sure if it is possible to create an interface to connect the app script to a external PHP application. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP IMAP Functions: imap_open, imap_fetchheader, imap_body etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can by using [**`search(query)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String))

> search Gmail with the given query.

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('is:starred subject:"IMPORTANT"');
```

Here is the list of [operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) you can use with Gmail.

---

For the trigger use **[Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)**

> A time-driven trigger (also called a clock trigger) is similar to a cron job in Unix. Time-driven triggers let scripts execute at a particular time or on a recurring interval, as frequently as every minute or as infrequently as once per month. (Note that an add-on can use a time-driven trigger once per hour at most.) The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m., then keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours elapse before the trigger fires again.

[*JDBC*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc)

> Apps Script can connect to external databases through the JDBC service, a wrapper around the standard Java Database Connectivity technology. In Apps Script, the JDBC service supports Google Cloud SQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle databases.

---

Getting the details of the mail use the Class [**`GmailMessage`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message)

> - `getDate()`
> - Gets the date and time of this message.
> - `getBody()`
> - Gets the HTML content of the body of this message.
> - `getFrom()`
> - Gets the sender of this message.
> - `getSubject()`
> - Gets the subject of this message.

Hope it can help!